# Can you create a React JS with cdn

Tags: reactjs

Can you use React js static website only using cdn link?
Im trying to create a static website on webhosting service.

Comment: What do you mean by reactjs static website?

Comment: https://github.com/morganney/cdn-react-prototyping

Answer (score 5):

Here is an all in one `index.html` with React v18

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>React without JSX</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
    const Example = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
      React.useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
      });
      return (
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
            Click me
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
    root.render(<Example />);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can — in fact, that's how the Stack Snippets feature here supports React.

Here's an example that uses [`createElement` instead of JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) (but keep reading):

```js
const Example = () => {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello, React!");
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Example), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That's probably want you want to do. You can still write JSX code, just compile it to non-JSX code (perhaps using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) before you put the compiled result in your public page. Or just write code using `createElement` directly.

---

You don't *have* to pre-compile JSX code, but you really, really should. It's *possible* to compile on-the-fly in the browser, but it takes a while, causing a significant delay on page load. But for completeness, here's how you can do that using the browser-hosted ["standalone" Babel library](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#docsNav):

```html
<!-- Your code that needs compiling goes in a type="text/babel" `script` tag -->
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
const Example = () => {
    return <div>Hello, React!</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>

<div id="root"></div>

<!-- This is what supports JSX compilation (and other transformations) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<!-- These are for React -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice the delay on startup.

Just for completeness, if you need to compile `async`/`await` to non-`async`/`await` for obsolete browsers, you need another script:

```html
<!-- This example supports `async` functions in obsolete environments that don't support them natively -->
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-3">
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args));
}

// Example component that has a `useEffect`
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Hello, React!");

    useEffect(() => {
        // A contrived async function for demo purposes only
        (async () => {
            await delay(800);
            setMessage("Hello again React!");
        })();
    }, []);

    return <div>{message}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>

<div id="root"></div>

<!-- This is the script providing runtime support for compiled `async`/`await` code -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.2/runtime.js"></script>
<!-- This is what supports JSX compilation (and other transformations) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<!-- These are for React -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice, again, the big delay on startup.

I suggest pre-compiling the code before putting it on the page, so it's more like the first snippet above that uses `createElement`, which is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

From what I am understanding is, you want to make a simple react app using CDN in suppose index.html

## Create one HTML file

Create `index.html` file and add the following content. This file contains the basic HTML boiler plate code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

## Include CDN links

Inside head section add

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

## Create react component like this in the file

- MainComponent is our react component
- React component name should start with Capital letter

```
<script type="text/babel">
    const MainContent = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Main content goes here...</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    //render the component to the DOM
    ReactDOM.render(<MainContent />, document.getElementById('main-content'));
</script>
```

## Open file

Open `index.html` file and you are done.